# Google Sheets import image and importxml function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the 1st product image using the image and importxml function in google sheets from a set of URLs. Here's an example set:

```
SKU                 URL                                         IMPORT IMAGE FORMULA
264757-WHITE    https://www.tedbaker.com/uk/p/264757-WHITE  ??
246367-BLACK    https://www.tedbaker.com/uk/p/246367-BLACK  ??
262100-LT-BLUE  https://www.tedbaker.com/uk/p/262100-LT-BLUE    
264793-BLACK    https://www.tedbaker.com/uk/p/264793-BLACK  
241424-BLACK    https://www.tedbaker.com/uk/p/241424-BLACK
```

The formula I tried does not work:
`=IMAGE(INDEX(IMPORTXML(B2,"//html/body/div[1]/main/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/img/"),1),1)`

Any help will be appreciated. I just want a formula that retrieves the 1st product image from the URLs in the data set. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=BYROW(B2:B,LAMBDA(X,IF(X<>"",IMAGE(IMPORTXML(X,"//div[@data-swiper-slide-index='0'][1]/img[1]/@data-src")),"")))
```

- In this case, the xpath is `//div[@data-swiper-slide-index='0'][1]/img[1]/@data-src`.

#### Testing:

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to use a formula for each cell, how about the following sample formula?

  ```
    =IMAGE(IMPORTXML(B2,"//div[@data-swiper-slide-index='0'][1]/img[1]/@data-src"))
  ```

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)

Comment: Very good work! Thank you for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jared Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.